# Collapsing SearchView when losing focus (support library)

Tags: java, android

I have SearchView in Toolbar as collapsible action view. And I wanted it to collapse every time it loses focus to something else, but only if it's empty.

This was the code I used:

```
svSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus && svSearchView.getQuery().toString().isEmpty()) {
                mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            }
});
```

I have recently upgraded Support library, so it's now on 27.0.1. I started also using new `Toolbar` instead of old integrated ActionBar.
Now I have problem that it crashes when I press UP button on SearchView (back arrow in top left corner). It's obviously problem that it tries to collapse in reality twice (first by my code and second by pressing UP button).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.mParent' on a null object reference
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.removeFromArray(ViewGroup.java:5035)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5232)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5194)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.collapseItemActionView(Toolbar.java:2401)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.collapseItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java:1370)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.collapseActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:828)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.collapseActionView(Toolbar.java:716)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$3.onClick(Toolbar.java:1381)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Do you know any recommended approach for this?

Comment: Can you post you full activity code? The crash is related to a NullPointerException and based on the code you posted, it isn't that section of code.

Comment: I can't unfortunately post the full activity code here. But the crash relates to the view parent that no longer exists when it has been already collapsed.

Comment: A simple fix would be to check if the SearchView's parent is null and return inside of the callback. The correct fix would be to prevent it from firing twice.

Comment: it's not pretty, but I found solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did this. It's not pretty, but it works. It prevents from collapsing twice.

```
    svSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
                if (!hasFocus && !mCollapsing && svSearchView.getQuery().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                }
                mCollapsing = false;
            });

            mSearchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    //something
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    mCollapsing = true;
                    return true;
                }
            });
```